# Laravel Moltin Cart call in custom repository

Tags: php, laravel, repository, cart, facade

I installed Moltin Cart on Laravel 4.2 and configured it as documentation suggests. Everything work perfect when I'm calling it from controller. Like Cart::insert() etc.

Problem is when I try to call same code in custom repository. I have this repository/namespace:

```
namespace MyApp\Repositories;

use MyApp\Interfaces\CartInterface;

class CartRepository implements CartInterface 

...
```

So when i call `Cart::insert` in some of my functions inside this CartRepository class I got errors like `"Class 'MyApp\Repositories\Cart' not found".` I tried many variations of USE after namespace but nothing work. I got new error like

> "Non-static method Moltin\Cart\Cart::insert() should not be called
>   statically, assuming $this from incompatible context"

or similar.

Answer (score 0):

How it usually be with programmers I find answer just after I put question. Before that I wandered around 1-2h.

So, solution is to put

> use Cart;

I tried everything but that. :)